# us variable names to draw charts in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the my data frame:

```
 dput(head(df,10))
structure(list(Users = c(200L, 305L, 358L, 419L, 492L, 576L, 
675L, 791L, 928L, 1087L), Transactions = c(460, 702.4, 823.2, 
964.8, 1130.8, 1325.3, 1553.2, 1820.4, 2133.5, 2500.4), Workload = c(100, 
109.9, 109.9, 110, 110, 110.1, 110.1, 110.2, 110.2, 110.3), HeapUsage = c(25, 
35.83, 36.47, 37.13, 37.79, 38.47, 39.17, 39.87, 40.59, 41.32
)), .Names = c("Users", "Transactions", "Workload", "HeapUsage"
), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to use the variable names. For example,

```
yv=c("HeapUsage") and xv=c("Users", "Transactions", "Workload")
```

I need to be able to create however many entries in `xv` vector against `yv` variable.

I tried this:

```
ggplot(df)+geom_point()+facet_wrap(yv~xv)
```

does not seem to be working. In this case, I need 3 different charts `yaxis` being `yv` and `xaxis` being 1. `Users`, 2. `Transactions` 3. `Workload`

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: You need to gather to long form, e.g. `library(tidyr) ; df %>% gather(variable, value, -HeapUsage) %>% ggplot(aes(x = HeapUsage, y = value)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~variable)`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? 

`library(reshape2)`
`df.melt=melt(df, id="HeapUsage")`

`ggplot(df.melt)+geom_point(aes(y=HeapUsage, x=value, group=variable, colour=variable))`

Comment: @alistaire, I'd need HeapUsage on the yaxis and three different charts

Comment: So flip `x` and `y` in `aes`. You may also want `scales = 'free_x'`, or `Workload` will look very cramped: `df %>% gather(variable, value, -HeapUsage) %>% ggplot(aes(x = value, y = HeapUsage)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~variable, scale = 'free_x')`

Comment: @lampishthing, I need to use y=yv (variable name) within the aes. I tried y=yv not seem to be working. How can I reference yv in y-axis?

Comment: You're looking for `aes_string`, probably. If so, I will close this with a reference to one of the many duplicates on that topic on SO.

Comment: Did you figure this out? How many graphs do you want to see? If you use facet wrap you will see 3. What do you want on your x axis?

Comment: @lampishthing, yes alistaire answer did it. thanks you.